# How to maintain Position of other views after removing a view from the ViewGroup?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to remove a view from one ViewGroup and add it to another ViewGroup without changing the position of sibling views of the original viewgroup ,
as android automatically chops off extra space after removing a view.

Please don't suggest changing visibility

Comment: Not possible...!!.. You can just make it INVISIBLE or GONE. You can not remove it without changing the positions of its siblings

Comment: Why?
Is there any way to add extra space in place of the removed view ?

Comment: change visibility of the view u don't want to "invisible" and replace your new view there

Comment: That will not meet my requirements

Answer (score 1):

then don't remove `View` just change the **Visibility** to `invisible`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this

```
setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
```